# Python For loop on string is not printing any result

Tags: python

I am using For loop to create a new string, but it is not printing any result.

```
new_str = ''
for char in 'dfdfadcodefgldfjdcodefdfepiddjcode':
    if char == 'c' and char =='o' and char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' and    char == 'e':
        new_str += char
print (new_str)
```

Comment: `char == 'c' and char =='o'` can never be true - a character only has a single value

Comment: You expression is equivalent to `(char == 'c') and (char =='o') and (char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') and (char == 'e')`

Comment: Did you mean `or` instead of `and`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do note that by using `and`, the moment your code evaluates a `False`, it will skip that condition.

For example,

```
s = 'd'
if s == 'c' and s == 'd':
    print ('pass')
else:
    print ('fail')
```

The above code will print `'fail'` because `s` has failed the first `s == 'c'` part.
However, if you change to:

```
s = 'd'
if s == 'c' or s == 'd':
    print ('pass')
else:
    print ('fail')
```

The above code will print `'pass'` because `s` has failed the first `s == 'c'` part but will go on to evaluate the second `s == 'd'` part.

Now if you wish to simply exclude `'c', 'o', 'e'` from your string, simply remove them from the `in` part:

```
new_str = ''
for char in 'dfdfadcodefgldfjdcodefdfepiddjcode':
    if char in 'abdfghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz':
        new_str += char
print (new_str)
```

Or you could:

```
new_str = ''
for char in 'dfdfadcodefgldfjdcodefdfepiddjcode':
    if char not in 'coe':
        new_str += char
print (new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove 'c' , 'o' and 'e' characters from string. If my assumption is ture then tou can use this snippet.

```
new_str = ''
for char in 'dfdfadcodefgldfjdcodefdfepiddjcode':
    if char != 'c' and char !='o' and char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' and char != 'e':
        new_str += char
print (new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_str` is empty, because the `if` condition never evaluates to true. If the intention is that the the character is appended if it matches one of the specified characters, you'll need to use `or` rather than `and`.